# Gear S3 Tizen : How to get keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, tizen, samsung-gear

I would like to provide a reply functionality in my application (Web Tizen 2.3.2). I am currently able to get the keyboard to pop up if I add an `<input>`, however it would be much better if I could implement the same thing as Samsung uses. Many Samsung apps use it. It must be a built-in functionality in Tizen OS.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about. I would like to be able to display this same exact screen when I press reply in my own application, just like few Samsung apps does on the watch or replying to a notification [image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain details "how samsung uses it "?

Comment: By "it" I mean the UI shown on the screenshot. When pressing reply on a notification, this UI is displayed. When pressing reply in other Samsung applications, there is that same exact UI displayed as well. I believe it means this is a feature built into the system. I would like to display this screen when I press a button in my application. Is it possible?

Comment: May be possible

Comment: can you please add more photos what actually you want with consecutive photos

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am not sure what else you would like to see. Basically I open my app --> Press a Button --> Display what the screenshot shows --> Back to my app with the text that was either spoken, written or selected in predefined response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the guide to display the keyboard as you want.

[check the session: Input Delegator in Wearable Applications](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-information-and-controls/application-controls/common-application-controls) Web version

[check the session: Input Delegator in Wearable Applications](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/application-management/application-controls/common-application-controls) Native version

Try this:

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/get_input", null, null, null, null, null);
tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null, function() {
    console.log("launch application control succeed");
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("launch application control failed. reason: " + e.message);}, null);
```

You can also call only the voice input, for example.

Comment: Thank you !!! :) I haven't had the time to test it, but scrolling down to "Input Delegator" seems to be exactly what I need :D !

Answer (score 1):

Notification can be shown on Samsung Gear using [Tizen Web Notification API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/application/notification#create).

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/create_content", 
            null, "image/png", null, null);

    var notificationDict = 
    {
    /* Notification content */
    content: "Notification Content",
    /* Path to the notification icon */
    iconPath: "images/image1.png",
    /* Path to the sound file to be played when the notification is displayed */
    soundPath: "",
    /* Device vibrates when the notification is displayed */
    vibration: true, 
    /* Application control to be launched when the user selects the notification */
    appControl: appControl
    };

    var notification = new tizen.StatusNotification("SIMPLE", "Simple notification", notificationDict);

    tizen.notification.post(notification);
```

But i could not add reply button using this API. I saw this feature on [Samsung Rich Notification SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/rich-notification). If your requirements meet with that you can use. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you :) But yeah it's really the window I have screenshot that I want to have. Samsung applications also uses inside app, not only on a notification. It must be somewhere else :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `List` UI control for showing these options.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you did understand my question. I am not trying to build that UI, I am trying to call that feature. I think this reply/typing feature is built into the system. Thank you